# JQuery Mobile & URL Parameters white flash on reload

Tags: jquery-mobile, cordova, url-parameters

I am using query mobile for a *phonegap* application, I am passing through parameters through the url to the next page.

For example:

```
main.html?id=1, menu.html?id=2 etc
```

To allow this I have to turn `ajaxEnabled` to false to allow it to pass through the information I need. In doing so I am unable to use transitions from page to page which means I get a white flash as the page reloads.

I am generating these links dynamically.

```
$.ajax({
url: 'URLTO WEBSERVER',
dataType: 'jsonp',
jsonp: 'jsoncallback',
timeout: 5000,
success: function(data, status){
$.each(data, function(i,item){ 
var list = '<li><a href="menu.html?idcat='+item.id_cat+'">'+item.category_cat+'</li>'
output.append(list);
});
},
error: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
alert( "Request failed: " + textStatus );
output.text('There was an error loading the data.')
}
});
```

Is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

you can use method jquery serialize data for your paramater.
via changePage method in jquery 
I hope solved :D

Comment: The links I am generating are dynamic from data pulled from a web service using ajax, would this made a difference? Is it possible you can give me an example?

Answer (score 0):

I think he is concerned about the "white plash page" that happens after the request is completed from server and then he calls changePage. 
He is not worried about how to send parameters to server etc. This is assuming all that is working fine.